# SELECT Earliest Date from Grouped Results in DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, group-by

From this table T2, I need to select the earliest date from each group by ID where the Prog is 'YY' and use it in `DATEDIFF` with respect to `EDate`:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
| ID |   SDate   |   Edate   | Prog |
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
|  1 | 4/12/2016 | 5/18/2016 | XX   |
|  1 | 4/1/2016  | 4/4/2016  | YY   |
|  1 | 5/23/2016 | 5/28/2016 | YY   |
|  2 | 9/21/2016 | 9/26/2016 | XX   |
|  2 | 8/7/2016  | 8/9/2016  | YY   |
|  3 | 8/2/2015  | 8/12/2015 | YY   |
|  3 | 4/12/2015 | 4/18/2015 | YY   |
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
```

And then show it with the aggregate level in Table T1 as the **Desired Output**:

```
+----+------+-----+-----------+------+
| ID | Name | Age |   SDate   | Days |
+----+------+-----+-----------+------+
|  1 | A    |  52 | 4/1/2016  |    3 |
|  2 | B    |  11 | 8/7/2016  |    2 |
|  3 | C    |  24 | 4/12/2015 |    6 |
+----+------+-----+-----------+------+
```

Attempt:

```
SELECT 
    T1.ID,
    T1.Name,
    T1.Age,
    MIN(T2.SDate) AS [SDate],
    --DATEDIFF(day,MIN(T2.SDate),T2.EDate) AS [Days]
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2
    ON T1.ID=T2.ID
WHERE T2.Prog='YY'
GROUP BY 
    T1.ID,
    T1.Name,
    T1.Age
```

I commented out the DATEDIFF function for Days since I am not sure how to formulate that. Obviously, something like `DATEDIFF(day,SELECT MIN(SDate) FROM T2 WHERE Prog='YY','Another Date')` won't work since I will get an overall MIN(SDate) which won't be partitioned by ID and I can't do `SELECT ID,MIN(SDate) FROM T2 WHERE Prog='YY' GROUP BY ID` in the inner subquery either since DATEDIFF will only accept a Date field.

So how do I extract MIN(SDate) and calculate the DATEDIFF for corresponding Edate, for each grouped ID in that case?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query and `DATEDIFF` _can_ accept a min aggregate date input.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Made question more precise

Comment: Do you want the min difference between the `SDate` and `EDate` columns?  Or do you want to wrap `EDate` in another aggregate function?

Comment: Difference between Min(SDate) and the corresponding EDate (not wrapped in an aggregate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `min` window function to get the min sdate for each id and use it for computing the date difference.

```
SELECT ID,NAME,Age,DATEDIFF(DD,SDate,EDate) 
FROM (
SELECT 
    T1.ID,
    T1.Name,
    T1.Age,
    MIN(CASE WHEN T2.PROG = 'YY' THEN T2.SDate END) OVER(PARTITION BY T2.ID) AS [SDate],
    T2.EDate
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MIN` as a window function:

```
SELECT  T1.ID,
        T1.Name,
        T1.Age,
        DATEDIFF(day,
                 MIN(T2.SDate) OVER PARTITION BY (T1.ID, T1.Name, T1.Age),
                 T2.EDate) AS [Days]
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T2.Prog = 'YY'
```